# Количество одинаковых записей

Tags: php, sql

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM charts");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  echo $r['date'].": ".mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), date FROM charts WHERE `date`='". $r['date'] ."' GROUP BY date"),0,0).", ";
}
```

Этот запрос выводит: 
    2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-02: 1, 2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-03: 11,

А нужно как-то так:
    2014-10-03: 11, 2014-10-02: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT distinct date FROM charts");

С другой стороны, это можно сделать одним запросом. Не проверял:

mysql_result(mysql_query("select group_concat(f) from (SELECT concat(date,': ', COUNT(*)) f FROM charts GROUP BY date) x");
```

Comment: Замените первую строку на мою.

Comment: $res=mysql_query("SELECT distinct date FROM charts");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 echo mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), date FROM charts WHERE `date`='". $r['date'] ."' GROUP BY date"),0,0).".0, ";
}
Спасибо!) исправил)